# Two day stay in Hong Kong but need help regarding accomodation with suitable check-in times

Tags: layovers, accommodation, children, hong-kong

I am travelling to India via Hong Kong in December with wife and two children (aged 2 and 5). It's a nine hour flight which reaches HK at 7.00 in the morning. I am having trouble finding a place to stay which has early check-in times.

Most hotels I found have 2pm check-in time. Since I have young children who will be exhausted after such a long journey, I was hoping to at least find them a comfortable place to rest. We have the same problem with Check-out times as well. Our flights are at 7pm and most hotels have check-out time as 11.00am. Plus we have a lot of luggage with us since we are going to India for more than a month.

Wondering if there any accommodation suggestions which would suit us. Also would a place near airport be a good Idea or the city?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hong Kong is a very popular stopover city and many hotels offer guaranteed early or/and late checkin.  Random examples, no affiliation or personal experience:

- [Royal Pacific Kowloon](https://www.sino-hotels.com/hk/royal-pacific/en/about-our-tsim-sha-tsui-kowloon-hotel/media-centre/traveller-perks/), 10AM checkin and 7PM checkout
- [Dorsett Mongkok](http://www.mongkok.dorsetthotels.com/mobile/check-in-out.html), fully flexible checkin/-out within any 26-hour window
- [This search on Expedia](https://www.expedia.com.sg/Kowloon-Hotels-Hotels-Allow-Early-Check-In.0-0-d6059-tHotelsallowearlycheckin.Travel-Guide-Filter-Hotels)

I would not recommend staying near the airport for a two-day stay, there's virtually nothing to do and the city is only half an hour away.

Comment: Thank you. These options are great help. Given me a direction now to go in.